# Motion and contradiction

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, aristotle, paradox, philosophy-of-physics

Zeno famously said an arrow cannot be in motion as it occupies some precise position at some precise time. And is thus at rest.

Modern physics resolves this by stating the arrow has momentum. It is its momentum that carries from one place to another. At any precise time it has a specific velocity. So it is not at rest.

To simplify our presentation let us reduce the arrow to a point, and suppose it to move in a straight line with no forces acting on it.

One then can identify the continua of time with the continua of the line.

So motion is time. And time is motion.

But it seems to me that the paradox of *rest* remains. Which in this pictures is this. That a continuum of only points is actually not a continuum. There is no [cohesion](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential+cohesive+%28infinity%2C1%29-topos).

Modern studies of the real line remove this paradox by stipulating that a [topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology) is present and this binds together points. One of course then notices that the points are actually not neccessary, only the continuum itself, that is the topology.

That is [pointless topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointless_topology) (pun presumably intended by the author of the coinage).

This then removes Zenos first prescription to be able to specify an exact moment in time. In this picture this cannot be done.

But if one wishes to retain points, one could try a different logic, say by saying the point is both a point and not a point - this resolves to false in classical logic, but if one drops the law of the excluded middle, then this is not so. Following this line of thought for intuitionistic logic, gives the notion of the rigid, infinitesimal line. Which is not a point - it is a line, but it is also a point - it is infinitesimal.

Does this work as a solution towards resolving Zenos paradox?

Comment: Seriously, we're going to re-litigate Zeno today? What's your definition of an infinitesimal? There are no infinitesimals in the real number system. Non-standard analysis is highly technical. And *nobody* really thinks there are infinitesimals in the physical world. Have you got a definition of infinitesimal other than that it's "a point and not a point?"

Comment: @user4894: for Robinsons non-standard analysis, you can just take an axiomatic description of the non-standard reals plus the transfer principle. You don't need the nitty-gritty of model theory except to justify it, and don't we do the same for the reals? You don't start looking into set-theoretical foundations when you look at the calculus?

Comment: I don't, but other people [have](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinitesimal+object) "An infinitesimal space is supposed to be a space whose extension is infinitely small, yet not necessarily perfectly small". The point of putting it in the terms that I did, was to connect it with Zenos argument and Aristotles.

Comment: yes, it's point's all the way down. Look @ Nassim Haramein - Crossing the Event Horizon for a more detailed reasoning behind this

Comment: Mozibur, this is totally irrelevant,  but I've read a lot of your posts, and I think you need [this](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/apostrophe) :)

Comment: @user132181: Thanks - seriously :). Apostrophes are confusing, so I've followed the last *dictum* - 'when in doubt don't use an apostrophe'. I'll try to be more careful from now on.

Comment: Aside: pointless topology does have points; they just enter the theory in a different way. And a related (and topical) notion is that of a [germ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics)).

Comment: @hurkyl: good point! there are different kind of points apart from Euclids 'extensionless point'.

Comment: Another modern view on Zeno and small distances, if you are interested: http://philpapers.org/archive/CTMPA.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In [Achilles and the Tortoise](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-zeno/), when Achilles  pursue the tortoise, he is not "counting" the point in space.

In the linear space continuum, points are not "isolated" entities : they are *cuts*. We have a "place before" (i.e. all numbers before SQRT(2)) the cut, and a "place after" the cut (all numbers after SQRT(2)) [this is Dedekind' analysis of the *continuum* : see [The Continuum and the Infinitesimal in the 19th Century](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuity/)].

Achilles will overtake the tortoise simply running (for example) twice faster than the tortoise: we do not need to assume that he has to run faster and faster ("count the natural numbers by counting faster and faster and faster").

We need to use a device to measure the progress of the run: if we use the heartbeat, and assume that the tortoise starts an heartbeat before Achilles, after the first interval in time *dt*, she [he, it ?] will have traversed a certain amount of space *ds*. With the second heartbeat Achilles will start, and we assume that he runs twice as faster as the tortoise. After the second heartbeat (i.e.after 2 x *dt*), both Achilles and the tortoise will have traversed a space equal to 2 x *ds*. After the third heartbeat, Achilles will have definitively outrun the tortoise (he have traversed a 4 x *ds*, while the tortoise has only traversed 3 x *ds*): this has required a finite amount of time (3 x *dt*) and without the need of an "unlimited increasing" speed.

If we model the race with the mathematical *continuum* we must not make the mistake of describing the progress of the runner as made of successive move from on point to "the next": in the real number line, a point has **no** "next".

We may say that Achilles will win because he is **not** counting the point in space; he is "traversing" intervals in time.

My personal "feeling" with this paradox is the same as the proposed solution in Wiki [Zeno's paradoxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Proposed_solutions) :

> > Pat Corvini offers a solution to the paradox of Achilles and the tortoise by first distinguishing the physical world from the abstract mathematics used to describe it. She claims the paradox arises from a subtle but fatal switch between the physical and abstract. Zeno's syllogism is as follows:
>
> P1: Achilles must first traverse an infinite number of divisions in order to reach the tortoise;
>
> P2: it is impossible for Achilles to traverse an infinite number of divisions;
>
> C: therefore, Achilles can never surpass the tortoise.
>
> > Corvini shows that P1 is a mathematical abstraction which cannot be applied directly to P2 which is a statement regarding the physical world. The physical world requires a resolution amount used to distinguish distance while mathematics can use any resolution.

See also [Zeno's Paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-zeno/) for further refences and Wesley Salmon, *Zeno's Paradoxes*, (2nd Ed - 2001).

Comment: Great answer! I deleted mine b/c yours is better.

Comment: Dedekind cuts is just one way to construct the real line by way of the rationals.  You could use Cauchy completion. Completion is about points - no *points* in a precisely defined way are missing.

Comment: If the topology on the line is *discrete*, then there is no sensible *idea* of moving from one point to another - recall, that a discrete space is [extremally disconnected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space); what I'm trying to point out in the question, or at least one part of it is this, is that topology or cohesion matters - which isn't seen in the standard solution.

Comment: I'm also, not talking about points as in the classical definition; of having no extension whatsoever; but as an infinitesimal extension: a point that is *not* a classical point, but in a sense is just pure extension.

Comment: Although isn't the particular problem of Zeno that I was discussing; it can be solved quite straight-forwardly using the *synthetic* plane geometry of Euclid - two straight lines that are not parallel must meet at a point, using this as the model for the problem gives us the time *t* when Achilles run past the tortoise; and redoing it in the analytic geometry of Descarte gives us the same answer - so long as we use the classical topology of the real line; using the discrete topology means there is no proof that the lines intersect, as the topology isn't *connected*.

Comment: Think of the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) used to build up the theory of real analysis - it fails with the discrete topology.

Comment: My point of view is the same for both paradoxes (Achilles and the arrow): their is a *physical* model of motion, based on *speed* that is measured, according to Galileo definition : "as the distance covered per unit of time". In physics we measure speed "counting" intervals of time (the heartbeat : Galileo was the first physicist to be able to measure little constant interval of time when there were **no** reliable clocks; he was son of a musicians, and, according to Stillman Drake reconstruction, he used the metronome). So motion is not modelled as a succession of ... 1/2

Comment: ... *jumps* from one point to the following one (this is the core of Zeno's paradoxes). Of course, you can defeat Zeno's paradox from the mathematical side (as Russell did) : the *sum* of the infinite series : 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... is the sum of an infinte number of quantities but it is still finite (this is the view from calculus), but I prefer the physical model of motion. 2/2

Comment: @allegranza: Yes, I agree that its the physical notion of motion that is important. What I'm questioning is the notion of *instantaneous motion* at a *durationless* instant, physically I think that this can't be right, and I believe that Aristotle makes the same point - however this doesn't mean that I don't think that it is very useful, it **is**; but this is like modelling the earth as a perfectly spherical object, it isn't of course, but the mathematical representation of it as such is useful.

Comment: The speed we measure is a *physical* one : space traversed in an interval of time. *Istantaneous* speed is a mathematical notion : the limit of the ratio Ds/Dt when Dt approaches to zero.

Comment: Sure, when we measure the speed of an object it is over an interval of time. Anyway the discussion that I'm trying to have is to *complicate* the usual reading of what a continuum means, this by no means *invalidates* the usual discussion of Zenos paradoxes in terms of the calculus. There are more than one way to manufacture an infinitesimal.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution is very similar to Whitehead's argument presented in Part I of *Process and Reality* and presupposed in the Theory of Extension in Part IV. If you recall from *Aims of Education* he holds that *a line is a "moving point" while a "plane is a moving line*." Along with von Neumann's work on mathematical rings, Whitehead relies on a continuous, *point-free* projective geometry of non-finite dimension. Whitehead's "extensa" or extensive structures are logically and metaphysically prior to time and space as topological relational systems (mathematically speaking, they may be seen as spatial, but this pertains to "spatial reasoning"). This allows for the openness in which "universal relativity" (not to be confused with Einstein's as only a single application) and "atomicity" are compatible. He writes:

> The creatures are atomic [i.e., undivided]. In the present cosmic
>   epoch there is a creation of continuity. Perhaps such creation is an
>   ultimate metaphysical truth holding of all cosmic epochs, but this
>   does not seem to be a necessary conclusion. The more likely opinion is
>   that extensive continuity is a special condition arising from the
>   society of creatures which constitute our immediate epoch (*PR*, 35-6).

This compatibility allows for the "becoming of continuity" and *not* a "continuity of becoming" as is assumed in Zeno's paradox. Under the conditions of our epoch

> The extensive continuity of the physical universe has usually been
>   construed to mean that there is a continuity of becoming. But if we
>   admit that ‘something becomes,’ [in the physical sense,] it is easy,
>   by employing Zeno’s method, to prove that there can be no continuity
>   of becoming. [Where we are speaking exclusively of the way that actual
>   entities, *considered physically rather than logically, divide the
>   extensive continuum there is a becoming of continuity, but no
>   continuity of becoming.* [Under those assumptions, the actual occasions
>   are the creatures which become, and [to that same extent, in the
>   physical sense only] they constitute a continuously extensive world.
>   In other words, [physically speaking,] *extensiveness becomes, but
>   ‘becoming’ is not itself extensive* (*PR*, 35).

Therefore, Zeno's paradox is a "mathematical fallacy" as Whitehead explains:

> In his ‘Achilles and the Tortoise’ Zeno produces an invalid argument
>   depending on ignorance of the theory of infinite convergent numerical
>   series. Eliminating the irrelevant details of the race and of
>   motion—*details which have endeared the paradox to the literature of
>   all ages*—consider the first half-second as one act of becoming, the
>   next quarter-second as another such act, the next eighth-second as yet
>   another, and so on in-definitely. *Zeno then illegitimately assumes
>   this infinite series of acts of becoming can never be exhausted.* But
>   there is no need to assume that an infinite series of acts of
>   becoming, with a first act, and each act with an immediate successor,†
>   is inexhaustible in the process of becoming. Simple arithmetic assures
>   us that the series just indicated will be exhausted in the period of
>   one second. The way is then open for the intervention of a new act of
>   becoming which lies beyond the whole series. Thus this paradox of Zeno
>   is based upon a mathematical fallacy. The modification of the ‘Arrow’
>   paradox, stated above, brings out the principle that every act of
>   becoming must have an immediate successor, if we admit that something
>   becomes. For otherwise we cannot point out what creature becomes as we
>   enter upon the second in question. But we cannot, in the absence of
>   some additional premise, infer that every act of becoming must have
>   had an immediate predecessor.The conclusion is that in every act of
>   becoming there is the becoming of something with temporal extension;
>   but that the act itself is not extensive, in the sense that it is
>   divisible into earlier and later acts of becoming which correspond to
>   the extensive divisibility of what has become (*PR*, 69, emphasis added).

Comment: Whitehead speaks as though *continuity of becoming* is natural & obvios, and Zeno shows that it is not. It would be worth spelling this out in more detail.

Comment: I revised my answer and added the full quote from Whitehead on Zeno to make it explicit. I think it is a rather cool argument that I hadn't heard until about three years ago. Something to consider at least. Thanks for another great question and I hope the clarification to what Whitehead thought about this as a mathematician and then metaphysician.

Comment: @Mozibur, he specifically says that there is NO continuity of becoming. Therefore, it's not "natural & obvious" in the way there is a becoming of continuity. He follows Locke's notion of "perpetual perishing" to describe the processes of transition and concrescence that makes reality "incurably atomic." This is why he is famous for the explanation that we experience "drops of experience."

Comment: I was focusing on this part of his exposition 'The extensive continuity of the physical universe has *usually* been construed to mean that there is a continuity of becoming.'

Comment: Ohh, okay. Well, he thought that was the common lens through which most understand motion. He complains that Descartes notion of "endurance" has done a lot of damage given its "superficial" meaning. He writes on previous page, "The difficulty is not evaded by assuming that something becomes at each non-extensive instant of time. For at the beginning of the second of time there is no next instant at which something can become."

Comment: The mathematical idea of the infinitesimal line thought *temporally* is, I think, in line with Whiteheads. He say 'The conclusion is that in every a of becoming there is the becoming of something with temporal extension' but 'that act is not extensive' in that 'it is divisible', well the infinitesimal line points in *potentia* to the past, and in *potentia* to the future, and itself is not divisible into anything *properly* smaller. I think its interesting that, in one line of argument of thinking about this, relies specifically on dispensing with the 'law of non-contradiction'.

Comment: and its interesting simply because the law of non-contradiction is pretty much an *absolute* principle as far as actual physical phenomena goes. And here we see it being dispensed with in the simplest motion.

Comment: @Jackson: okay, I see how he's using Zeno to dismiss the *continuity of becoming*, presumably this is Descarts idea of something *persisting*.

Comment: You got it, Mozibur! And that's why I said that I agree with your approach in the question--it's the feasible way to tackle it. You are also right that Whitehead only accepts Givenness and Freedom as "absolute" in the full sense and is on guard against "the notion of one ideal [that] arises from the disastrous overmoralization of thought under the in-fluence of fanaticism, or pedantry. The notion of a dominant ideal peculiar to each actual entity is Platonic [not Plato]" (PR, 84). It's a cool use of Zeno to me because it gives Zeno the credit he deserves while critiquing the conundrum.

Comment: I'm not sure if I quite said that, but seeing that I agree with it perhaps it was implicit in my 'discourse', Giveness being what *is*, and Freedom, being Becoming. And absolute, as they are irreducible to anything less. Does Whitehead link up with Hegels discourse on Becoming, I'm trying to see where his philosophy fits in with the Anglo-American discourse as it seems to stray pretty far whats considered as such now. Seeing that I mentioned *pointless topology* as a contemporary innovation, it seems Whitehead was its instigator as in [mereotopology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mereotopology)

Comment: That is correct! I'm so glad you are making these connections because admittedly I, along with others, struggle to break it all down. I have read a powerful book chapter that makes the textual claim that his mereotopology and theory of space are indeed what you say. Computer scientists are looking into Whitehead's theory of extension has a metaphysical basis for robotic vision, so I'm pretty excited to see these divergent fields in conversation. Yes, I think it was implicit in your response and that's how I read it. I appreciate your work this was another exciting question for me!

Comment: He is dismissive of Hegel but there are obvious connections. Please look at Robert Cummings Neville's chapter on the subject in his book, The Highroad Around Modernism. This is a really good book and Neville is a kind, great philosopher! He is the former dean of the School of Theology at Boston University.

Comment: @Jackson: Whiteheads prose is hard going, because he assumes philosophical idioms that I'm not familiar with; and presumably its not contemporary idiom either, though the mathematical and physical situation is clear  (to the extent it can be clear). Thaks for the book-tip, I'll look it up when I have the chance. I'd be interested to know a little more about the history of philosophy in Europe then, as Russel, Whiteheads partner in the *Principia*, seems to be a key figure in turning Anglo-Amex philosophy down the analytical road.

Comment: Its puzzling that they were such close collaborators when their philosophies were so different. Or perhaps not - he alludes to atomism too.

Comment: @Jackson: Going back to Whiteheads prose, its helpful to me to see what his prose might mean potentially & philosophically, as you've done. It also illuminates the way current philosophical idiom works too - ie Giviness & Freedom.

Comment: Yep, Whitehead was Russell's teacher and was impressed by the young lad. Although he always had his doubts about the Principia project he was intensely involved until 1910 and the fourth volume never appeared. If you read their correspondence (some of which has been published) you will see Whitehead thinks Russell is dishonest and a terrible philosopher. It's one of the reasons why he read philosophy without knowing any of the secondary literature. Actually, it was Whitehead who warned his student you are ruining philosophical reflection and impoverishing it. They had a funny relationship.

Comment: Yes, several mathematicians have told me Whitehead is straight poetry with a robust mathematics behind it and I can see that. But I'm very fortunate to have had great teachers who helped me struggle with it for years. It is very difficult, especially if you have been trained in so many other areas like myself. In order to read Whitehead it requires breaking a whole lot of bad readings, which were needed so one could grow. Whitehead will not only make you re-read everyone, but with fresh and enlivened eyes. It was well worth the struggle and effort to me!

Comment: @Jackson: ok, that fits in with Russells dismissal of the Philosophy of Antiquity, and Wittgenstein was Russells student...possibly further impoverishment there. The Tractatus, his early philosophy makes no mention of any antecedents by *name*, presumably, seeing itself as *sui generis*; possibly picking up Russells bad habits in relation with the Tradition; Whitehead understands that in mathematics that the *aximatic* is a contingent, whereas Russell & Wittgenstein take it as an End.

Comment: Exactly. Whitehead's response to philosophy of language in Wittgenstein's sense is an important subject to me and I have written on it. He views it rather harshly, but in a way that he can said he has done it--he worked with Russell and seen how it goes down. There is a similar affinity that occurs between Russell and Wittgenstein in that teacher-student dynamic as well. Solid connections, Mozibur!!